# Conditional splitting of column in multiple rows in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql, split

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
col1    other_name
1       Galantamine
2       Galantamine::::Propane
3       null
4       Galantamine::::Propane::::Methane
```

I would like to split the value in other_name in multiple rows

The desired output is:

```
col1    other_name
1       Galantamine
2       Galantamine
2       Propane
3       null
4       Galantamine
4       Propane
4       Methane
```

I am trying following queries:

```
select col1,
       coalesce(btrim(regexp_split_to_table(col2,'::::')), col2, null) as col2
```

I am getting following error while running above query:

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 0A000]  ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
  Hinweis: You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what the hint told you and move the set returning function into the `FROM` clause:

```
select t.col1, u.other_name
from the_table t
   left join unnest(string_to_array(t.other_name, '::::')) as u(other_Name) on true
order by t.col1;
```

The `left join` is necessary because the `unnest` will return no rows for the row with a `null` value in `other_name` and a `cross join` would remove that row entirely. As we don't need a real join condition, I use `on true` to satisfy the syntax requirements of the `left join` operator.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=70bba4eff05c7b7f110c1d3f7d8a09cf)